# Xcode failed to update app version number

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, versioning

I have flutter project and I want archive for iOS app.

Let's say I set the version to 3.0.0 in `identity` section
[image]

Then after archive, the version still remain as 1.0.0 (1) but not 3.0.0
[image]

Besides that, the `Version` in my `pubspec.yaml` is 1.0.0+1
If I set the version in yaml file to 3.0.0 and run `flutter build ios`
Then the archive app version is 3.0.0

But from the flutter document [https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios](https://stackoverflow.com)  we can override it in Xcode.
[image]

Extra info (my software version)

- macOS 13.3.1
- Xcode 14.3
- flutter 3.7.12

Now my question is we can't overwrite the app version in Xcode ?